# Why is not the thread object destroyed after scope?

Tags: java, multithreading, scope

I thought that objects only exist in the scope that they've been defined. But in this program, after execution of `thtest` method, `t1` object of thread still exists and I can see both "hi" and "bye" in output.

```
public class apples {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int b =1;
        navid n = new navid();
        n.thtest(); 
        while (b==1){ System.out.println("bye"); }  
    }
}
```

---

```
public class navid {
    int a=1;
    public void thtest (){
        Runnable te = new Runnable() {
            public void run(){
                try{
                    while (a==1){ System.out.println("hi");}
                }catch(Exception e){}
            }   
        };
        Thread t1 = new Thread (te);
        t1.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what a `Thread` is?

Comment: Its working as per you coded.

Comment: a path of execution ?

Comment: Note that you can just do `while(true)` if you want an infinite loop.

Comment: yeah , your right , i'm kind of a new user of java , i was trying while(1) and it would give me an error of not Boolean , thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I thought that objects only exist in the scope that they've been defined.

This is a wrong assumption. Objects exists until there's no more references to them (or until it is garbage collected, depending on your view). You can store references to your objects other places than where they are defined, and make them live as long as you desire.

Threads are somewhat special, the JVM will keep track of a thread and it will continue to run until its `run()` method ends, even if your code contains no references to the Thread object.

Comment: so , with out a reference it is not possible to have an access to the object after the scope . the object just exist in memory with out any path of access to it . am i right ?

Comment: @user2555974 No. *Variables* have scope, and references to the same object can be placed in lots of different variables. An object will not be garbage collected as long as some reference to it is held by some live thread.

Comment: For most purposes, objects never stop existing, you just lose access to them. You should only need to think about garbage collection if you're having memory problems.

Answer (score 0):

**References** die after scope, **objects** live as long as they are being used, by user or by (in your case)JVM.

Comment: what do you mean by reference ? could you give me an example of it

Comment: Reference variable he's talking about.
A ref=new A();
ref is a reference variable. If A is a class.

Comment: so , with out a reference it is not possible to have an access to the object after the scope . the object just exist in memory with out any path of access to it . am i right ?